# Setting default color in Windows Forms

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, button

I'm creating a simple GUI using Powershell and Windows Forms for a set of scripts I have written.

I've generated a bunch of buttons in the GUI and I'm currently in the process of adding styles to my buttons.

```
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

Is there anyway to set the below set of lines as a global/default setting of sorts for all buttons?

```
$Button1.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Button1.BackColor = '#CCCC99'
$Button1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
```

To give you an idea, what I'm doing now is adding the block of text for every button.

```
$Button1.BackColor = '#CCCC99'
$Button2.BackColor = '#CCCC99'
$Button3.BackColor = '#CCCC99'
etc...
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better and more efficient way to do this. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I expect all buttons to look pretty much the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all of the buttons after they have been created and set their properties, like TheMadTechnician suggests…

But there is a better way. Think object-oriented programming. You have a `Button` class, and you want to change its default properties. In fact, you want *all* of your buttons to have those new properties. So really, what you want is a custom control that is *like* a button but slightly different.

Well, what do you know? There's a linguistic way to express that:

```cs
public class MyBeautifulButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public MyBeautifulButton()
    {
        // Set default properties here...
    }
}
```

You can even go one fancier and override the specific properties, setting the appropriate attributes, to change their default values.

Then, instead of creating `System.Windows.Forms.Button` objects in your PowerShell code, you will create `MyBeautifulButton` objects.

Although I must say that I don't think the result will be terribly beautiful. The BackColor property of a button is one of those that I don't think should have ever been provided. Button controls are designed to be drawn using the system theme, which specifies the colors for you. It also allows the users to customize the colors as desired. Application-specified colors usually result in a visually jarring and downright ugly UI. Don't let your app stick out like a sore thumb. Buttons are utility controls. Consistency is key. Remember that GUI applications are not web pages.

Comment: This is so much better of a solution than mine. I had no idea how to do that, thank you Cody Gray, this is getting stuffed away in my snippets folder so I can write better scripts in the future. Great answers like these remind me how very much I have yet to learn.

Comment: You should show how to do it in PowerShell rather than C#

Comment: I'm not sure if you can create custom classes in PowerShell. The only way I've ever done it is writing classes in a .NET language, compiling them, and using Add-Type in PowerShell to access them. To be fair, I'm not a big PowerShell user. Perhaps it's inertia, but I still find batch scripts to be much more efficient. If I need to do something complicated, I'll either write a C# app or a C++ app. I kind of glossed over the PowerShell aspect of the question. If you really can't create derived classes in the scripting language, then perhaps this is not a good solution after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for that Cody. You are right on the money - I am looking for this exact functionality in Powershell. I've read from a different thread that this can be done using 'Add-Type' and am looking into it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just apply that to all buttons after you add them to the form? Something along the lines of:

```
$MyForm.Controls | Where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "Button"} | ForEach{$_.BackColor = '#CCCC99'}
```

Comment: Thanks bud. I've found that 'Add-Type' is the most succinct way to accomplish this but while learning I've used this method on the interim. Cheers!